# Scrapy - cannot get the values in the table

Tags: python, scrapy

this is the [html page](https://www.twse.com.tw/indicesReport/MI_5MINS_HIST?response=html&date=20191101)

here is my scrapy code

```
import scrapy

class get_taiex(scrapy.Spider):
    name='get_taiex'
    def start_requests(self):
        url ='https://www.twse.com.tw/indicesReport/MI_5MINS_HIST?response=html&date=20191101'
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath('//tbody/tr'):
            yield {
                'date' : row.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract_first(),
                'open' : row.xpath('td[2]/text()').extract_first(),
                'high' : row.xpath('td[3]/text()').extract_first(),
                'low' : row.xpath('td[4]/text()').extract_first(),
                'close' : row.xpath('td[5]/text()').extract_first()
            }
```

I don't know why it doesn't work

It works fine with [this page](https://www.tpex.org.tw/web/stock/aftertrading/daily_close_quotes/stk_quote_result.php?l=zh-tw&o=htm&d=108/11/20)

The difference is just a div tag

and I use this for json output

> scrapy crawl get_taiex  -o output.json -t json

thanks.

Comment: Is necesary to use scrapy?...I mean ...I can help you using beautiful soup

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar Yes, I just start a scrapy project for multiple crawlers, is it suitable for using beautiful soup in scrapy project?

Comment: it depend what kind data(web) are you crawling....with this web ...is enough with  beautiful soup

Comment: Would you kindly add a result that you're getting?

Comment: @Tino It outputs an empty json file

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar I will try if I can't handle with scrapy. Thanks

Comment: @DeepBreath I checked the structure of both pages (like you mentioned they are equal and the xpath statement should be fine). The main difference between the one working for you and the one not. The latter is taking a substantial time to load... Try to check if the `response` object exist when you start looping through the rows.

Comment: @DeepBreath It's funny. I copy-pasted your code and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably using new version scrapy you get `Forbidden by robots.txt` therefore you get empty `response` so you need to make change in your `setting.py`:

```py
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```